# How to get current, selected menu item in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

please advise me how to get//read parent of currently selected item in menu .... Wordpress//PHP

Example:

Menu structure:

A
-aa
-ab
-ac

B
-ba
-bb
-bc

So, if user chooses, let say "ba" item then I need to get "B" item (...)

Thank You

Comment: i dont undestand what you want to do can you please explain with images ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about are breadcrumbs. This should help: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-page-parent-on-page-with-title

Essentially: `$post->post_parent` will give you the ID of the parent page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the parent page of the current page, you can use [Get Post Parent Id](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_parent_id) or you can use ancestor https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_ancestors

Answer (score 0):

Thank You all for tips and guides.

I have solved this in this way:

```
$current_page_id = $post->ID;
$page_children = fnGetPageChildren($current_page_id);

class currentpage_child {
    var $title;var $link;
        function set_data ($page_title,$page_link){
            $this->title = $page_title;
            $this->link = $page_link;
        }
}

function fnGetPageChildren ($page_id){
                    // Set up the objects needed
                    $my_wp_query = new WP_Query();
                    $all_wp_pages = $my_wp_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page'));

                    //get current page parrent id
                    $parent_id = wp_get_post_parent_id($page_id);
                    //get current page parent title
                    $parent_title = get_the_title($parent_id);

                    // Get the page as an Object
                    $obj_get_help =  get_page_by_title($parent_title);

                    // Filter through all pages and find Portfolio's children
                    $get_help_children = get_page_children( $obj_get_help->ID, $all_wp_pages);

                    $childrenpages_count = 0;
                        foreach ($get_help_children as $obj) {
                            $arr_currentpage_children[$childrenpages_count] = new currentpage_child();
                            $arr_currentpage_children[$childrenpages_count] -> set_data ($obj->post_title,$obj->guid);
                            $childrenpages_count++;
                        }

                    return $arr_currentpage_children;
            }
```